# Cannot connect to Wristband via bluetooth on Windows phone 8.1

Tags: bluetooth

Cannot connect to Wristband via bluetooth on Windows phone 8.1 because i need to enter some letters in Bluetooth pin, but i can enterjust numbers. how can i enter the letters to the bluetooth pin?

Comment: what wristband are you trying to connect?